# How to return a combination of SliverAppBar and SliverList in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I have an app that has a cart screen, in this screen I want to divide the ordered products according to their respective factories, so I want to use `SliverAppBar`s and `SliverList`s.

Now what I really need is to make a custom widget that can returns a `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverList` together so that I build this widget and get multiple `SliverAppBar`s and `SliverList`s.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a package on pub.dev that can do that, it's called sliver_tools and here's the link to it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)